# ASP.NET 5 Unit Test controller with UserManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, moq

I started to use ASP.NET 5 (vNext) and now I'm trying to unit test a controller that uses **UserManager** to register and login users.

I'm using **xUnit** and **moq.netcore**.

In my UnitTest I have:

```
var mockStore = new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>(MockBehavior.Strict).As<IUserPasswordStore<ApplicationUser>>();

mockStore.Setup(x => x.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<ApplicationUser>(), CancellationToken.None)).Returns(Task.FromResult(new IdentityResult()));

var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(mockStore.Object, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

And the code in the controller:

```
var result = await _securityManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

But, when I run the unit test I get a null exception, when calling CreateAsync.

I don't understand why I can't Mock the CreateAsync method with ApplicationUser and string parameters, and I have to mock it with the CancellationToken.

It's my first project using ASP.NET 5, I was using ASP.NET 4.6 before, so a lot of things are different now.

And, do you think I should already develop an important project in ASP.NET 5 or should I wait and develop it for ASP.NET 4.6?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After trying a lot of things I came up with a working solution.

### UserManager

I created a FakeUserManager class that inherits UserManager and overrides CreateAsync method.

```
public class FakeUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public FakeUserManager()
        : base(new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().Object,
              new Mock<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Object,
              new Mock<IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>>().Object,
              new IUserValidator<ApplicationUser>[0],
              new IPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>[0],
              new Mock<ILookupNormalizer>().Object,
              new Mock<IdentityErrorDescriber>().Object,
              new Mock<IServiceProvider>().Object,
              new Mock<ILogger<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>>().Object,
              new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>().Object)
    { }

    public override Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user, string password)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success);
    }
}
```

Then I passed a new instance of FakeUserManager to AccountController constructor and it works fine.

---

### SignInManager

And for those that may need to mock SignInManager I did it the following way:

I created a FakeSignInManager class that inherits SignInManager and overrides the methods I need.

```
public class FakeSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public FakeSignInManager(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
        : base(new FakeUserManager(),
              contextAccessor,
              new Mock<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>>().Object,
              new Mock<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Object,
              new Mock<ILogger<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>>().Object)
    {
    }

    public override Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent, string authenticationMethod = null)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public override Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(SignInResult.Success);
    }

    public override Task SignOutAsync()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

And since SignInManager need a context accessor to work I made FakeSignInManager receive it in the constructor.

Then, before creating a new instance of SignInManager I prepare a new HttpContextAccessor the following way:

```
var context = new Mock<HttpContext>();
var contextAccessor = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();
contextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext).Returns(context.Object);
```

And then create the new FakeSignInManager instance:

```
new FakeSignInManager(contextAccessor.Object);
```

Comment: Don't waste too much time on ASP.NET 5 until they release the RC2 of the ASPNET Core... I've read somewhere that the Identity system you're using won't be included in the framework, and the team itself reccomends Identity Server (a third party project) for this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will avoid obsolete work then.